# Wordpress: how to change the table name in get_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress I just want to the change the table get_posts() uses for a single query. How to do this? please help

Comment: Change table name ? This is unrealistic. Why you need to do so ?

Comment: Have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50305/how-to-extend-wp-query-to-include-custom-table-in-query